# Changing name of uploaded file in contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I would like to change the name of file (saving the extension of the file, only name has to be changes) which a user may upload using form prepared in Contact Form 7. I know that there is a special filter for it:

```
wpcf7_upload_file_name
```

but I have absolutely no idea how to use it to change file name. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the `change` event on the field. Then separate the name and extension of the file, construct the name. Create a new file with the new name using the `File` WEB API.

```
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    let file = e.target.files[0];

    let split_name = file.name.split('.');
    let name = 'wpcf7_upload_file_name.' + split_name[ split_name.length - 1 ];

    let blob = file.slice(0, file.size, file.type);
    let new_file = new File([blob], name, { type: file.type } );

    const data_transfer = new DataTransfer();
    data_transfer.items.add(new_file);
    e.target.files = data_transfer.files;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Khalil, much apperciated your comment. The thing is that I would like to change the file's name then save it in difined location on my FTP, right after submission. I know how to save a file but still don't know how to connect it with changing it's name. I would also prefer to do it in PHP. Is it possible?